# Hibernate query returns null

Tags: java, hibernate-criteria

I have this query in java-hibernate and I want to return this result. But returns null. How can I fix it?

```
BigDecimal totalbalance = null;
Query query = session.createQuery("select sum(beforeBalance) from DepositTransaction");
totalbalance = (BigDecimal) query;

return new BigDecimal(totalbalance+"");
```

Comment: You're not running the query, just trying to cast the query object into your result variable won't work. You need to actually execute the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HQL syntax is a bit off.  Try this instead:

```
BigDecimal totalbalance = null;
String theQuery = "select sum(dt.beforeBalance) from DepositTransaction dt";
Query query = session.createQuery(theQuery);
totalbalance = (BigDecimal) query.getSingleResult();

return totalbalance;
```

This assumes that your `DepositTransaction` class has a field called `beforeBalance` with a getter method.

Answer (score 0):

first you have to execute the query:

```
List<BigDecimal> result = (List<BigDecimal>)query.list();
```

Then you have to check the result

```
if (result.length()!=0){
   return result.get(0)
}
return null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
totalbalance = (BigDecimal) query.getSingleResult();
return totalbalance;
```

instead of

```
totalbalance = (BigDecimal) query;
```

Answer (score 0):

As that look like a native query you should use createNativeQuery.
You should also only look for a single result so use getSingleResult

```
BigDecimal totalbalance = null;
String yourQuery = "select sum(dt.beforeBalance) from DepositTransaction dt";
Query query = session.createNativeQuery(yourQuery);
return new BigDecimal((BigDecimal) query.getSingleResult());
```

Answer (score 0):

Approach using SQLQuery object:

```
String query = "select sum(beforeBalance) from DepositTransaction";
BigDecimal totalBalance = (BigDecimal)session.createSQLQuery(query).list().get(0);
return totalBalance;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `totalbalance = (BigDecimal)query.uniqueResult();`